# Is it possible to drop-create some table with JPA

Tags: jpa

You can in the persistance.xml set tables to be dropped and recreated on startup. Is it possible to be more selective having some tables stay populated and others recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately such feature (and even more) is supported starting from JPA 2.1 by using the following set of properties:

```xml
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" 
value="drop-and-create"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" 
value="script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" 
value="script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" 
value="META-INF/drop-script.sql"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" 
value="META-INF/create-script.sql"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" 
value="META-INF/load-script.sql"/>
```

In the above example `javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source` informs provider to use scripts for creating, deleting or loading the database schema specified in the corresponding property values:

- *drop-script.sql*:  `DROP TABLE ...` statements
- *create-script.sql*: `CREATE TABLE ...` statements
- *load-script.sql*: `INSERT INTO ...` statements

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)